# How to prove this condition doesn't force the sequence to be a null sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_0)$ be a real sequence.
Why does this condition not force $(a_0)$ to be a null sequence (so converges to 0)?

For every $\epsilon > 0$ exists such a number $n_0 \in ℕ$ that for every $n ≥ n_0$:
$|2a_n - a_n^2| < \epsilon$

I have tried multiple different ways of adjusting it to fit into the general definition of $|a_n - 0| < \epsilon$, but it doesn't work out. I can't find a way in my head since $|a_n|$ is not defined in any way.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the constant sequence $a_n=2$.

Comment: More generally, we can see that a sequence $(a_n)$ will satisfy these requirements if and only if for all $\delta > 0$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \ge N$ one has either $|a_n|<\delta$ or $|a_n-2|<\delta$. This is because the function $f(x) = x^2-2x$ has exactly two zeros, being $0$ and $2$.

Answer (score 2):

Take for example the sequence

$$a_n=\begin{cases}0, \;\;\text{if n is odd}\\{}\\2\,\;\;\text{if n is even}\end{cases} \implies \{a_n\}=\{0, 2, 0, 2, \ldots\}$$

Then your sequence trivially fulfills the condition yet it is not a null sequence